# Adding to the values of dictionaries using variables and raw_input

Tags: python, variables, dictionary, raw-input

This is a re-post of my last question which wasn't very clear. Here is what I have:

```
cf={p1:50}
inc = raw_input('Enter Amount of Increase: ').lower()
if inc > 0:
    num = inc
    float(num)
    for p1 in cf:
        cf[p1] = num + cf[p1]

print cf[p1]
```

This code keeps on giving me the answer 250 for some reason when I input 2. I am hoping for the answer 52 when I input 2. I think what is happening is it is adding adding the number I input in front of the 50 instead of adding 50 + the input to find the sum of the 2 numbers. Is there anyway I can fix this?

Comment: cf[p1] = num + cf[p1] would appear to be just adding the 2 in front of your current value of 50, to give 250, but it shouldn't be happening since you are concantenating a string('2') with an int(50)...

Comment: If your program expects numbers, why are you calling `str.lower` on the input?

Answer (score 2):

```
float(num)
```

doesn't change `num` to a float it returns the floating point number of the string `num`. Try

```
num = float(num)
```

Also, you are doing a comparison `inc > 0` on the string `inc` which will always be `True` as long as it has a value. You should probably cast the input to a `float` before doing this.

```
cf = {p1: 50}
inc = raw_input('Enter Amount of Increase: ')
num = float(inc)
if num > 0:
    for p1 in cf:
        cf[p1] = num + cf[p1]

print cf[p1]
```

Comment: Excellent. I'm glad we could help. Here's a reference on accepting answers on SO. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/245475 Best practice is to accept an answer once your issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

inc is a string when it is input, '2'

Example:

```
>>>    inc = raw_input("Enter number: ")
Enter number: 2
>>>    type(inc)
str
```

the value of `cf[p1]` is an int 50, according to your code above anyway

to actually convert num to a float you need to do

`num = float(num)`

`float(num)` by itself makes no assignments

All together:

```
inc = input("Enter Amount of Increase: ")
num = float(inc) #shorter way
if num > 0:
    for p1 in cf:
        cf[p1] += num # adds num to the value in cf[p1]

print cf[p1]
```

Note that cf[p1] will now itself be a float. When you add an int to a float the result
is a float.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `input` as it runs `eval` and could potentially lead to unintended consequences. IMO, it's safer to read in the string and cast it accordingly with `raw_input`. Depends on the application though, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did using bnjmn's answer:

```
inc = raw_input('Enter Amount of Increase: ').lower()
def cva(x):
    return x + 50
if inc > str(0):
    num = inc
    num = float(num)
    print cva(num)
```

I made a simple function